# GWT visualization API Motion Chart language

Tags: gwt, localization

I'm using the gwt visualization library to display motion charts in a gwt app. However, the language shown in the chart is random (different language every time it loads).

This:
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/using_overview.html#localization
says I can set it, but only through the load method. But the GWT load method does not allow me to set anything other than the version and Packages.

As far as I can tell, there is no way of explicitly setting the language using the GWT API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that this is a bug, which I've submitted here:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/detail?id=358

Answer (score 1):

You can set the locale of a GWT application in many ways: [Locales in GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html). My guess would be that the Visualization API uses that value to set its own locale value.

You should be able to do a quick test of this by appending `locale=fr` (change to your desired locale) to the address:

```
http://www.example.com/MyGwtApp.html?locale=fr
```

This will force that locale to be used by GWT.

---

Update: the [`AjaxLoader`](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.0/com/google/gwt/ajaxloader/client/AjaxLoader.html) does support setting the language via the [`AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions`](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.0/com/google/gwt/ajaxloader/client/AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions.html):

```
AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
options.setLanguage("fr");
AjaxLoader.loadApi("visualization", "1", null, options);
```

I'm not sure you can use `null` for the callback parameter, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first will hopefully be useful in future, but looking through AjaxLoaderOptions suggests that the language isn't linked to GWT's locale thing.

I spotted the second as well, and thought that would be it, but for some reason it does absolutely nothing for me!

I'm thinking it might be a bug. Let me know if you have tried it and got it to work reliably. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is based only on the docs. But it seems you are right - recently someone reported a bug report about this: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/detail?id=341 You should vote for that bug (and maybe provide some extra info in the comments there, like a code snippet) - you'll get notifications when it's resolved then too.